# Python: Printing ASCII text file using curses library

Tags: python, printing, ascii, curses

I'm trying to print a text file that contains ASCII art in python.

I realize the easy way would be do something like this

```
with open(image, 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

but I want to print it using the curses library so that I can display other text along with the image. Here is what I've come up with so far.

```
lines=[]
with open('image.txt',"r",encoding="utf8") as f:
        lines.append(f.readlines())

for a in lines:
    char = str(("".join(a)))
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, char)
```

This code does 90% of the job but I cant get the image to shift to the right. I can choose which row the image begins on by changing the y in stdscr.addstr(y, x, char)  but changing x has no effect on which column it starts in.

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `lines.append()`, you're taking the entire list returned by `f.readlines()`, and adding it to `lines` as a single item. `for a in lines`, then, loops only once, joining the elements of `a` (the entire file) back together and passing that to `addstr()`, which interprets the embedded line feeds, resetting each line after the first to the first column.

Instead of `lines.append()`, you either want `lines.extend()`, or, more likely, just `lines = f.readlines()`. You can then dispense with the join, although you should probably strip the line feeds. E.g.:

```
with open('image.txt',"r",encoding="utf8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for a in lines:
    # set x and y here
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, a.rstrip())
```